# Thymeleaf don't expand data-<name> attribute on body tag

Tags: spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf, tomcat7

I have to downgraded a project with Spring Boot + Thymeleaf to make it work on **Tomcat 7** for reasons of the production environment.

I have a Thymelead template where I collect some variables on HTML body tag:

```
<body th:title="${key}" th:data-key="${key}" th:data-rol="${rol}" th:data-iden="${iden}">
```

The title attribute was introduced to see that the variable 'key' is collected.

In the original project with Thymeleaf 3.0 (running on Tomcat 8.5) all the variables was collected but with the downgrade to **Thymeleaf 2.1.6** only the attribute title is initialized.

Is there any possibility to make the template works with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a way to turn on that functionality in Thymeleaf 2, that being said the alternative syntax would be this (should work in all versions):

```
<body th:title="${key}" th:attr="data-key=${key},data-rol=${rol},data-iden=${iden}">
```